# How to get class type from member pointer template type

Tags: c++, templates

For sorting user defined typed objects in a flexible way (i.e. by naming a member variable) I wrote a template to generate lambdas to do the comparison. Additionally to chain comparisons of different member variables in case of equality I wrote a second template. It works so far but I want bpth templates to be completely independent from any concrete types. Therefore I have to get a class type from a class member pointer type.

This is my user defined example type:

```
struct Person { string name; int age, height; };
```

To sort objects of it by looking at e.g. the age I  want to write it like:

```
auto result = max_element(persons.begin(), persons.end(), order_by(&Person::age));
```

This works with the template:

```
template<class F> //F is Person::* e.g. &Person::age
auto order_by(F f) {
    return [f](const Person& smaller, const Person& bigger) {
        return smaller.*f < bigger.*f;
    };
}
```

To be able to chain multiple comparisons in case of equal values like this:

```
result = max_element(persons.begin(), persons.end(), order_by(&Person::age) | order_by(&Person::height));
```

I wrote the template:

```
//compose two orderings :
template<class F1, class F2>
auto operator|(F1 f1, F2 f2) {
    return [f1, f2](auto a, auto b) {
        auto res = f1(a, b);
        auto inv_res = f1(b, a);
        if (res != inv_res)
            return res;
        return f2(a, b);
    };
}
```

Here the first comparison is done and if it detects that a==b (a is not smaller than b and b is not smaller than a) it uses the second comparison function.

What I want to achieve is to be independent of the Person type in the first template. How could this be solved?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Does changing `const Person&` to `const auto&` achieve what you intend? Otherwise it is possible to write a simple type trait to deduce the class a member pointer belongs to. It would be easier to definitely answer with a [MCVE].

Comment: Whats wrong with `return [f](const F& smaller, const F& bigger) ...` not sure if I understand the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 `F` is a member pointer type, not the class type.

Comment: oh ok got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily extract the class and type of the pointer-to-member in your first template with some small modifications.

```
template<class Class, class Type>
auto order_by(Type Class::* f) {
    return [f](const Class& smaller, const Class& bigger) {
        return smaller.*f < bigger.*f;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the class type from the type of a pointer to member like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int bar;
};

template <typename T> 
struct type_from_member;

template <typename M,typename T>
struct type_from_member< M T::* > {
    using type = T;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same< type_from_member<decltype(&Foo::bar)>::type, Foo>::value;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Because `type_from_member< decltype(&Foo::bar)>::type` is `Foo`.

So you could use it like this:

```
template<class F> //F is Person::* e.g. &Person::age
auto order_by(F f) {
    using T = typename type_from_member<F>::type;
    return [f](const T& smaller, const T& bigger) {
        return smaller.*f < bigger.*f;
    };
}
```

Comment: And combinations increase even more to handle ref qualifier, `volatile`, C-elipsis :-/.

Comment: BTW, OP uses non-method members.

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed. Actually I was expecting to get downvoted. What is the easy way to get all combinations? Its a bit strange that `std::mem_fn` has no alias for the class type

Comment: @Jarod42 oh I had to read the question three times to really understand it :/

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to have all combinations for function_traits, the only way I see is to enumerate all (The only thing that can be factorized is between regular functions and member functions (so [abominable function types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) appears)) and their pointer version, (and alias of functor to their operator()).

Comment: @Jarod42 I confused `std::mem_fn` with some type trait, that I don't find anymore. Anyhow the trait i was looking for is deprecated. `std::mem_fn`s return type has some really weird member aliases. Understandable that they are removed in C++20

Answer (score 1):

I would forward job to `std::tuple` with something like:

```
template <typename... Projs>
auto order_by(Projs... projs) {
    return [=](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return std::forward_as_tuple(std::invoke(projs, lhs)...)
             < std::forward_as_tuple(std::invoke(projs, rhs)...);
    };
}
```

with usage

```
result = std::max_element(persons.begin(), persons.end(), order_by(&Person::age, &Person::height));
```

ranges algorithms (C++20 or range-v3) separate comparison from projection, so you might have (by changing `order_by` to `project_to`):

```
result = ranges::max_element(persons, std::less<>{}, project_to(&Person::age, &Person::height));
```